# How do I check if a cron expression executes daily, weekly or monthly?

Tags: java, cronexpression

Is there any easy way to do it other than comparing the characters in the cron expression with all the possible characters?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29318310/180100) could help (computing the next two dates then doing a diff)

Answer (score 2):

with help from RC's comment. I came up with this. This will return the difference in days.

```
String cron = "0 0 12 * * ? *";
CronExpression cronExpression = new CronExpression(cron);
Date date1 = cronExpression.getNextValidTimeAfter(new Date());
Date date2 = cronExpression.getNextValidTimeAfter(date1);
long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
long days = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. check cron log file

   cat /var/log/sysog | grep CRON
2. create a cron job that write the current time to a file, then evaluate

   */1 * * * * echo $(date) >> cron.log